# How do I solve X in this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 9\\-4 & 7\end{bmatrix}X + \begin{bmatrix}-5 & 5\\3 & 4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-2 & 2\\5 & -7\end{bmatrix}X$$

I'm pretty sure you would do $AX + B= CX$.

And then to solve for $X$ you would do
$$AX+B=CX\implies X=(C-A)^{-1}\cdot B.$$

I keep getting the wrong answer so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. It might be the arithmetic? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: My calculations are (C-A) which gave me $$\begin{bmatrix}-3 & -7\\9 & -14\end{bmatrix}$$ Then I did the inverse of the (C-A) which gave me $$\begin{bmatrix}-14/105 & 7/105\\-9/105 & -3/105\end{bmatrix}$$ I then multiplied it with B which gave me $$\begin{bmatrix}91/105 & -42/105\\36/105 & -59/105\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: `It might be the arithmetic?` Could well be. One way to verify would be to post your calculations. More often than not, you'll spot the error before finishing.

Comment: Well I just rechecked and I did do the arithmetic wrong. I somehow added -45 and -12 and got -59 instead of -57.